# React native: Virtualbox linux kernel driver not present or permission problems

Tags: react-native, virtualbox, genymotion, linux-mint

I am trying to run genymotion but the virtualbox(latest version 5.2.18) it keeps giving me the following errors:[virtualbox launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXTpb.png)

[genymotion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aszWh.png)
I did try applying the solutions provided but still did not work. I am using linux mint 19 cinnamon, with kernel version=4.15.20, required header is present with same version as kernel version.Hence I will like to ask if the problem is with the folder permission or otherwise and how it can be fixed.

[folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0qwb.png)